# div with curved border, no corners

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes, margins

I have to make a container with very strange margins. I tried to make it with :after and :before, but had problems with borders style.[Image of a div I have to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZCOy.png)

Comment: I think the best way is to use an image

Comment: can this be done with HTML5 Canvas? I don't use it so don't know its limittions, but it may be able to. Or a SVG but again, I dont't have exeperience with them.

Comment: i also never work with them, hoped, there're a way to do it with HTML5 and CSS3

Comment: html border can't be oddly shaped, create an svg using inkscape or any other editor and set it as a background image to the div.

Comment: @Romanbtc, since this shape has multiple curves/etc, and would have to be repeated to create the smaller 'inner border', it would be in your best interests to use an SVG image instead.

Comment: @jbutler483 Thank you. I got it to work. It's what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
Just exported my layer in Photoshop as SVG, and post that .xml code in HTML5.
And it works perfectly.